# How Can I Add a Binding to a Resource Dictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I have several controls on my `UserControl` that use the same Visibility Binding:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Whatever.MyClass"
             x:Name ="TheUserControlName"
             DataContext="MyUserControlViewModel">

    <Label x:Name="MyLabel" 
           Visibility="{Binding SomeBoolean, 
               ConverterParameter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter},
               Converter={StaticResource BooleanValueInverter}}"
       Style="{StaticResource LeftLabel}"
       Content="Template _Name"
       Target="{Binding ElementName=SomeTextBox}" />
</UserControl>
```

I tried to add the binding to the `UserControl.Resources` dictionary:

```
<Binding x:Key="IsCourseVisibilityBinding"
         Path="Thing.SomeBoolean"
         ConverterParameter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}"
         Converter="{StaticResource BooleanValueInverter}" />
```

... and I get the error:

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Value' property of type
>   'DictionaryEntry'.  A 'Binding' Can only be set on a
>   DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject`

... but then it occured to me that maybe I should be putting a `Visibility` value in the resource dictionary... but I can't get that to work either.

How can I refactor the Visibility Binding so that I only have to define it once?

Comment: SomeBoolean is a _read-only property_ of my ViewModel.  I've added a name to my UserControl.

Comment: It sounds to me like the error is saying that I'm trying to _set a binding_ on the DictionaryEntry that is the `UserControl.Resources` collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. But you may want to use dynamic resources. Create visibility resource(s) inside App.xaml like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary
      <Visibility x:Key="SomeVisibility">Visible</Visibility>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

To bind to this visibility anywhere from XAML:

```
<Button Content="Some button" Visibility="{DynamicResource SomeVisibility}"/>
```

Now to change value of this resource you can call this anywhere from code:

```
 Application.Current.Resources["SomeVisibility"] = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

**Edit**: Actually you can define dynamic resources for specific user control if you don't want them to be global in all application.