# Change value of a system variable in xaml resource dictionary from view model mvvm

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid, resourcedictionary

I have a Datagrid which uses a ResourceDictionary to define it's style.

```
<DataGrid  Style="{StaticResource HistoryViewDataGridStyle}" .....>
</DataGrid>
```

And in the ResourceDictionary I have below style defined.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" x:Key="HistoryViewDataGridStyle">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>.....
```

Now I want to use a application wide font color and font size for DataGrids, where user can change the values.
I am using a mvvm model and I managed to give user a drop down list of colors and font sizes.

I am looking for a method to use system variables in resource dictionary,

```
<sys:Double x:Key="DFontSize">12</sys:Double>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FontColorBrush" Color="Black"/>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" x:Key="HistoryViewDataGridStyle">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value=**FontColorBrush** />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value=**DFontSize**/>
```

Is there a way that I can set values to these system variables from code behind and change the datagrid style accordingly.

Please comment your suggestions.

Thanks
Mathee

Comment: You can do this with dynamic resources. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396964/how-can-i-add-a-binding-to-a-resource-dictionary/37416464#37416464) may help you.

Comment: do I have to make both setter value inside resourceDictionary and the Datagrid style as Dynamic Resources. I get cast invalid error when doing so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***It depends upon whether you want to save these new settings or not ?***

If yes, then you have to use `Application Settings`. Right click *Project > Properties > Settings*, and create a setting of type `System.Windows.Style` (PresentationFramework.dll assembly).

If no, then use `DynamicResource` binding instead of `StaticResource`.

[Settings class in C# (Codeproject)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17659/How-To-Use-the-Settings-Class-in-C)

[How to create Application Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171565(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Using Settings in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: do I have to make both setter value inside resourceDictionary and the Datagrid style as Dynamic Resources. I get cast invalid error when doing so

Comment: And also I want to change the style instantly when user select from drop down. Can we use this in such way